# multithreaded OpenSSL on ubuntu 14 link errors with OPENSSL_THREADS

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, openssl

I just upgraded from **Ubuntu 10** to **Ubuntu 14** and now get link errors when I try to build app server that uses OpenSSL.  This occurs only on functions related to multithreading support e.g., `CRYPTO_num_locks()`.  These functions still exist in the `/usr/include/openssl` headers, but seem not to be in the libraries I have.  I installed via:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

#define OPENSSL_THREAD_DEFINES
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
```

results in `OPENSSL_THREADS` being defined, which is supposed to mean the libraries support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `-lcrypto` to the `gcc` linker command line.  I guess these functions got moved to their own library at some point, or something else was letting the linker find them on **Ubuntu 10**.  I have to thank RedHat for pointing this out.  It produced same error as ubuntu gcc, but with additional suggestion to add `libcrypto.so` to the command line.